# ggplot 2 facet_grid "free_y" but forcing Y axis to be rounded to nearest whole number

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using:

```
facet_grid(SomeGroup ~, scales="free_y")
```

Is it possible to specify that although you want the scales to be "free" you want them to be in rounded to the nearest whole numbers?

Any assistance woudl be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Given that `breaks` in scales can take a function, I would imagine that you could wrap the basic breaking algorithm in a function that doesn't allow non-integers.

Start with an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_grid(am+cyl~., scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Looking at how `scales::pretty_breaks` is put together, make a function that wraps it and only allows integer breaks through:

```
library("scales")
integer_breaks <- function(n = 5, ...) {
  breaker <- pretty_breaks(n, ...)
  function(x) {
     breaks <- breaker(x)
     breaks[breaks == floor(breaks)]
  }
}
```

Now use the function this returns as the `breaks` function in the scale

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_grid(am+cyl~., scales="free_y") +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = integer_breaks())
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you very much.  I also, didnt know about pretty_breaks so your reference to that was very helpful as I intend to use that a lot.

Answer (score 8):

I might be missing something here, but I would do something like this.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   facet_grid(am+cyl~., scales="free_y", space = "free_y") +
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, 2), expand = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think your solution works just fine if you knew in advance where to set the breaks, whereas with Brian Diggs anwser you need not know in advance.  I appreciate your help and I found your anwser's use of: space = "free_y" and expand = c(0, 1) to be especially informative as I was not aware of those features.